# Breaking the line in between the code in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

I have a file with line(s) that look like this:

```
<url><loc>URL</loc><lastmod>Date</lastmod><changefreq>Time</changefreq>
```

I'm editing the file in Notepad++,
and I want to be able to break the HTML at its structural boundaries;
e.g., I want the result to be:

```
<url>
<loc>URL</loc>
<lastmod>Date</lastmod>
<changefreq>Time</changefreq>
```

How can I do this in Notepad++?

Answer (score 2):

Use search and replace, and make sure Extended Search Mode is enabled, then replace `><` with `>\n<` which will match (and add) exactly 3 new lines

Answer (score -2):

Go to **View -> Word Wrap**. Make sure that is checked.

Change the search mode to **Extended** then use `\n`.

Comment: And then do what?  Finding `>` and replacing with `>\n` is too broad; it produces seven lines, rather than the desired four.

Comment: Treat it like XML. Use [this plugin for notepad](http://geek.sylvainw.com/2010/03/28/using-notepad-to-quickly-format-xml) Or maybe there's a standalone XML formatter out there. If you're running php already, the Dom parser will format it correctly for you.

Comment: Please comment on downvotes so that it can be improved :)